# Insert resultSet into ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, resultset

I've spend all day looking for this and as far as I checked I always stick with an empty ArrayList. I also tried to display just the first record I find and I got null. What should be inserted into ArrayList are only courses, so Strings.

```
public String getProfessorCourses(){
       ................       
       //get the id related of the name
   String s = null;
   String sqlQuery = "SELECT courses.title FROM courses INNER JOIN professors_courses ON professors_courses.course_id = course.course_id WHERE prof_id = '"+1+"'";

       ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

       try {
         rst = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

       try {
           //titles are not inserted
            while(rst.next()){
              //s = new String(rst.getString(1));
              //s = rst.getString(1);
                          s = new String(rst.getString("title"));    
                }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       .........................   
       return s;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

where are you inserting data into the array list? You need this line after:

s = new String(rst.getString("title"));

```
result.add(s)
```